# ionic 1 pushPlugin $cordovaPush:notificationReceived case message not fired when app is in background

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework

I am using cordova [pushPlugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/)

In that the code in my app.js under `$ionicPlatform.ready` I  have,

```
$cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {
                // Success
              //  console.log(result);
  }, function(err) {
                // Error
              //  console.log(err);
   });

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', 
        function(event, notification) {

                console.log('event',notification.event)
                switch(notification.event) {
                    case 'registered':
                        if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
                            //alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
                            window.localStorage['push_token'] = notification.regid;

                            if(window.localStorage.getItem('id') != null){

                                console.log(3, 'api')
                                var addDevicetoken = myConfig.ApiBaseUrl+'api/addDeviceToken';

                                var postData = {
                                   'id'           : window.localStorage['id'],
                                   'device_token' : notification.regid,
                                   'device_type'  : 0, // android
                                   'uuid'         : uuid
                                };

                                appRequestApi.requestPost(addDevicetoken,postData).then(function(result){

                                    console.log(result);
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'message':

                        console.log(notification);
                        // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
                        alert('message = ' + notification.message + ' msgCount = ' + notification.msgcnt);
                        break;

                    case 'error':
                        alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
                        break;

                    default:
                        alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
                        break;
                }
            });`
```

the message event does not trigger when my app is in background.

And also I am sending the payload from laravel as

```
$push = new PushNotification('fcm');

    $push->setMessage([
        'data' => [
            'title' => $title,
            'body' => $message,
            'content-available' => 1,
            'notification_type' => $notification_type,
             'icon' => 'ic_launcher',
        ]
    ])
    ->setDevicesToken($tokens)
    ->send();
  //  dd($push->getFeedback());
    return true;
```

Please help